# Can the BlueSmirf Gold bluetooth module communicate logical HIGH/LOW instead of serial?

Tags: digital-logic, bluetooth, android

I am wondering if the [BlueSmirf Gold](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10268) can set HIGH/LOW commands instead of serial communication?

I am writing a small andorid app to control something via the BlueSmirf. I know how to establish serial communication using it, and how to transmit data by following the Bluetooth Chat example

```
public void write(byte[] buffer) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(buffer);

            // Share the sent message back to the UI Activity
            mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Exception during write", e);
        }
    }
```

But I want to send HIGH (1) or LOW (0) instead of serial communications. I believe that if I will be sending 0 or 1 in the current setup it will not set it to low or high. Any ideas on how I can achieve it?

Thank you

Comment: Can your device send an UART BREAK? Some UARTs can send a break for any length of time. A break turns the TX line active or the opposite polarity as inactive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the module is capable of using some of the pins as GPIO (general purpose IO), but unfortunately, the board doesn't break any of the usable pins out.  You'd have to solder another connection onto one of the unused pins.  PIO9 on pin 32 (the 4th from the left on the top) isn't multiplexed, so it's probably the least troublesome to use.  To do so, send the following commands (taken from the GPIO section of the [advanced user manual](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Wireless/Bluetooth/rn-bluetooth-um.pdf)) over the link:

```
$$$          enters command mode (no other commands for 1 sec before and after)
S*,0200      drives GPIO-9 low
S*,0202      drives GPIO-9 high
```

Comment: how about using the Rx, Tx, CTS, or RTS to get this result?

Comment: Thanks, I will try it tonight. When you say 4th from the left on the top, which top do you refer to? The side with the blue antenna or the 6 pinouts? - Thanks

Comment: The side with the 6 pinouts.  I'm not aware of any reliable way to use the Rx, Tx, etc. pins to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Hello again, I reviewed the schematic and PIO9 is pin 33. Which one is better? 33 or 32? Thanks

Comment: Roving networks' [datasheet](http://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Wireless/Bluetooth/Bluetooth-RN-41-DS.pdf) shows it as pin 32.  I would tend to trust that over SparkFun's schematic, especially since they didn't even connect that pin.

Comment: yea, was just going to comment about this error between the datasheet and the schematic. OK, here goes pin 32.

Comment: one last question about this topic, whats the fastest that PIO9 would switch at? Any chance it will get to 38kHz?

Comment: The serial link won't go higher than 921Kbps.  It takes 8 bytes per character and 8 characters to send the toggle command.  Two toggle commands per cycle gives you a max of 7.2 KHz.  If you have requirements like that, you're probably going to end up happier if you just hook the module up to an arduino or something.

Comment: Does the CR counts as a character? ok... so if I will go in a different direction - can i control the output voltage of any of the pins?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9630/discussion-between-karl-bielefeldt-and-kingsinnersoul)